# how does Angular $http cache key get created

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

It does not specific in the Angular docs how $http checks the cache for existing keys.

For example, when I do:

```
$http.get("/search/11", { cache: true });
```

The cache will obviously work.

But what if i do

```
$http.get("/search", { cache: true, params: { age: 11 } });
```

Or the more complicated

```
$http.post("/search", objectParams, { cache: true });
```

Will it by pass cache if I change one of the properties of `objectParams`?

The more general question is, how does Angular know when to serve from cache vs make a new request? Does it compare just the url, the params, the postload, or all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache key is the url built by `buildUrl` function in `http.js`([src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/http.js#L1025)):

```
url = buildUrl(config.url, config.params);
```

which creates a url with a query string part : `?key1=val1&key2=val2` out of `config.params`.

So,

```
$http.get("/search", {cache: true, params: {key1: "val1"}})
// or
$http.post("/search", postData, {cache: true, params: {key1: "val1"}})
```

will have a cache key of `"/search?key1=val1"`